# How can I position the labels for my pie chart appropriately?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

So I'm making a pie chart, and [I am attempting to recreate this](https://live.zoomdata.com/zoomdata/visualization?__target=embedded&key=52265abb6abdbcaa8c217789#51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346db-51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346d5)

However, I can barely position my text labels to not get obscured by the pie slices. Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahdp2/)

Setting the `z-index` for the `text` attribute in the above fiddle doesn't inhibit it from being obscured.

In addition, how can I assure that the labels are outside the pie chart? I tried setting an offset from the center on the labels, but then they are obscured by the edges of the svg.

Any input would be awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating SVG Element Z-Index With D3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595175/updating-svg-element-z-index-with-d3)

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053424/label-outside-arc-pie-chart-d3-js)?

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21939977/3128209)?  There are a number of others on the "related" sidebar that should get you started.