# D3js: Horizontal lines in pie chart work, but don't understand code

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

I love [this](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799) pie chart. It slices the lines to the text labels. Those labels are placed in a way that the lines are perfectly horizontal. And although the code is on the page there, I don't understand how this is done.

Guess it's this part:

```
function midAngle(d){
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
}
text.transition().duration(1000)
    .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
        this._current = this._current || d;
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            var d2 = interpolate(t);
            var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
            pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
            return "translate("+ pos +")";
        };
    })
```

Tried to read the docs and get the concept of start/endangle, but failed.

I was playing around with a pie chart that can handle collapsing of labels (http://jsfiddle.net/8QvvF/ after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939977/d3-js-spreading-labels-for-pie-charts) post) and hoped to be able to turn it into a chart with horizontal lines that exit the arc **exactly in it's middle**.

Can anyone please tell me what this code does or give me a hint how to modify my fiddle?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you want the segments that exit to shrink towards the centroid of the segment? This would assume that both segments next to it grow by the same amount, no?

Comment: Thanks Lars. I tried to modify the anti collapsing pie chart into the chart below from the second screenshot. So lines should start at the center of an arch (already works), exit the arch exactly at the middle [I think that’s (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 ], and then turn into an horizontal line that slices to the text.  I need to place the labels on the left/right side of the chart, so d.x needs to be something like d.x = labelRadius * (center < Math.PI ? 1 : -1 ) I assume (http://jsfiddle.net/ZE5Wc/1/). But I don't know how to place x.y in order to make the lines exit archs in the middle.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do. Is all you have trouble with placing the line segment that's pointing to the centroid of the segment?

Comment: Yes! Placing the line segment that'S pointing to the centroid of the segment AND still keep the horizontal endings of the lines.

Comment: Here is another try: http://jsfiddle.net/uPH7x/. Managed to make the line exit exactly at the centroid, but unfortunately "lost" the horizontal lines.