# Find intersection of SVG path

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Is there a known method for finding the intersect of an SVG path **with itself**?  Take the ampersand for example, **&**, it's one line that intersects itself at two points.

I have come across an [intersection library](http://www.kevlindev.com/geometry/2D/intersections/index.htm) but it seems to talk of two shapes intersecting, rather than one intersecting itself.

I'm familiar with d3 so any javascript based answer would be great, but also happy to hear what mathematical approach could be used.

Thanks

Comment: Hopefully a math inclined person will come through and answer this question well. In the mean time, here's a thought: if you express the path as a series of straight (non-collinear) segments, then you just have to check whether any segment intersects with any of the other segments (excluding the 2 segments it's connected to). Finding the [intersection of two segments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection) is rather straightforward. However, if the path consists of hundreds of segments, this can become computationally expensive.

Comment: To get you started, the d3 quadtree object and methods are useful for finding elements that are geometrically close to each other.  [Here's an answer I wrote using quadtree to avoid overlapping rectangular labels](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21998197/3128209).  For working with a single path, you'd start by splitting the path into individual segments and finding the bounding box for each, then use the quadtree to identify overlapping BBoxes.  If your path only contains straight lines, testing for intersections is straightforward, but for arbitrary curves it would get tricky.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are right - the library from Kevin Lindsey ([@thelonious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736745/thelonious)) seems to do the job here.

You tell the library to look for intersections between two instances of the same shape, strip out `Vector2D` objects, and what is left are 2 sets of the same intersection points (`Point2D` type objects in his library).

This is the main part:

```
var pathEl = path.node();
var intersections = [];

// Kevin Lindsey's library
var shape1 = new Path(pathEl);
var overlays = Intersection.intersectShapes(shape1, shape1);

for (i in overlays.points) {
    if (overlays.points[i].getName() == "Point2D") {
       intersections.push(overlays.points[i]);   
    }
}
```

Full embedded example below:

```js
var ampersand = "M 72.184621,99.39089 C 68.398038,95.61996 48.405425,73.700329 50.716835,49.985704 C 52.990823,26.655017 76.884556,12.578576 98.97427,11.448114 C 119.34404,10.405671 142.83345,16.156173 152.28457,35.843184 C 162.40413,56.922579 150.99532,81.842705 134.24772,94.48352 C 128.42088,98.881524 127.0609,99.082849 118.46055,102.84216 C 106.06795,108.25911 93.590914,113.54803 80.869078,118.1294 C 54.582831,127.59557 34.539139,149.03858 35.259701,178.23878 C 35.916374,204.84994 59.631137,225.67546 85.210802,229.70364 C 112.43115,233.99018 134.41358,229.54707 153.1347,208.67628 C 161.17912,199.70814 177.58763,184.99294 185.76751,176.14503 C 200.25035,160.47941 207.7442,147.82465 213.06419,126.69158 C 216.66826,112.37483 192.54569,115.67347 196.78314,103.62942 C 222.23036,100.69638 247.81229,99.84462 273.34564,97.96536 C 277.34887,109.81154 263.97786,106.33066 246.61613,121.01207 C 227.0104,137.59107 217.88679,151.73768 201.01195,170.86236 L 189.11358,184.34708 C 181.10521,193.42317 167.95634,207.85044 159.78314,216.77784 C 142.32024,235.85217 126.21297,247.41796 100.27427,252.39343 C 72.543606,257.71262 39.651129,254.69839 20.122962,231.94973 C -0.62641014,207.77846 -4.0848351,167.90434 18.462826,143.66847 C 33.171306,127.85873 41.031184,120.17885 60.724466,112.09432 C 76.147466,105.76283 100.05575,99.431353 112.29677,94.160526 C 139.69178,82.364582 140.40896,53.478721 127.50818,32.380115 C 116.44184,14.281646 83.908653,15.752833 77.904904,37.000557 C 72.689417,55.458561 80.089538,67.982449 91.37226,80.93907 L 187.58994,191.43156 C 199.42503,205.63979 217.24414,228.88851 237.39579,232.51125 C 250.72342,234.90721 267.9319,228.93995 277.27793,220.4821 C 282.25334,229.49138 275.03265,236.84049 269.43939,242.49659 C 251.14471,260.99681 219.58458,257.23653 199.30993,242.48439 C 187.00911,233.53413 178.95611,227.18492 167.95716,215.15746 L 72.184621,99.39089 z ";

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300);

var path = svg.append("svg:path")
            .attr("d",ampersand)
            .style("stroke-width", 2)
            .style("stroke", "steelblue")
            .style("fill", "none");

// Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332422/how-do-i-get-the-name-of-an-objects-type-in-javascript
Object.prototype.getName = function() { 
   var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
   var results = (funcNameRegex).exec((this).constructor.toString());
   return (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : "";
};

// Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array
function uniq(a) {
    var prims = {"boolean":{}, "number":{}, "string":{}}, objs = [];

    return a.filter(function(item) {
        var type = typeof item;
        if(type in prims)
            return prims[type].hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (prims[type][item] = true);
        else
            return objs.indexOf(item) >= 0 ? false : objs.push(item);
    });
}

var pathEl = path.node();
var intersections = [];

// Kevin Lindsey's library
var shape1 = new Path(pathEl);
var overlays = Intersection.intersectShapes(shape1, shape1);

for (i in overlays.points) {
   if (overlays.points[i].constructor.name == "Point2D") {
      intersections.push(overlays.points[i]);   
   }
}

// The path will record 2 points for each intersection, so deduping is necessary
var deduped_intersections = uniq(intersections);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                 .data(deduped_intersections)
                .enter()
                 .append("circle");

var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
                       .attr("r", "3")
                       .style("fill", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/2D.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice!  It's always great to discover that someone else has done the hard parts, but thanks for putting it all together in such an elegant snippet.  I'm sure there will come a time when I need a similar function.

Comment: Thanks for a great working example mccannf.  I swapped your ampersand path with my own though, and no Point2D intersections are found http://bl.ocks.org/danharr/3931242a8b5a1a76d2a3 only Vector2D co-ords http://bl.ocks.org/danharr/2002b2fd98cb09f71522 Is there a certain way the original svg path needs to be for this approach to work?

Comment: @DanHarrington - ooops :( you've found the example that doesn't work, this looks like it invalidates the intersection library as a candidate to solve this...I've looked, and the real intersection points are in those Vector2D coordinates, but there is no way to filter them out from the false matches.

Comment: The "uniq" function doesn't work - change it with this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicate-values-from-js-array/14740171#14740171

Also the reference to 2D.js should be changed to:

http://www.kevlindev.com/gui/2D.js

Why the examples of Dan Harrington don't work is still to be solved.

Original code example uses a closed SVG path defined with absolute curves while Dan's have relative curves (e.g. point coordinates in a path). Changing them to absolute doesn't help.