# d3 pie chart not displaying all labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying a simple pie chart with labels inside the slices. I can display the labels but all not all. e.g. in the sample code I have Rick 5%, Paul 4% and Steve 3% are not displayed because of the small size of the slices. How can I overcome the problem?

```
<html>
<head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing Pie Chart</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v2.js"></script>-->
    <script src="../js/d3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

        #pieChart {    
            position:absolute;
            top:10px;
            left:10px;
            width:400px;
            height: 400px; 
        }

        #lineChart {    
            position:absolute;
            top:10px;
            left:410px;
            height: 150px;
        }

        #barChart {
            position:absolute;
            top:160px;
            left:410px;
            height: 250px;
        }

        .slice {
            font-size: 8pt;
            font-family: Verdana;
            fill: white; //svg specific - instead of color
            font-weight: normal ;   
        } 

        /*for line chart*/
        .axis path, .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: black;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges; //The shape-rendering property is an SVG attribute, used here to make sure our axis and its tick mark lines are pixel-perfect. 
        }

        .line {
            fill: none;
            /*stroke: steelblue;*/
            stroke-width: 3px;
        }

        .dot {
            /*fill: white;*/
            /*stroke: steelblue;*/
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }


        .axis text {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        .title {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 15px;    

        }

        .xAxis {
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 11px;
            fill: black;
        }  

        .yAxis {
            font-family: verdana;
            font-size: 11px;
            fill: white;
        }


        table {
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border: 0px;    
            font-family: Verdana;   
            color: #5C5558;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: right;          
        }

        td {
            padding-left: 10px;     
        }

        #lineChartTitle1 {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size  : 14px;
            fill       : lightgrey;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-anchor: middle;
        }

        #lineChartTitle2 {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size  : 72px;
            fill       : grey;
            text-anchor: middle;
            font-weight: bold;
            /*font-style: italic;*/
        }

    </style>

</head>
<body>

        var formatAsPercentage = d3.format("%"),
                formatAsPercentage1Dec = d3.format(".1%"),
                formatAsInteger = d3.format(","),
                fsec = d3.time.format("%S s"),
                fmin = d3.time.format("%M m"),
                fhou = d3.time.format("%H h"),
                fwee = d3.time.format("%a"),
                fdat = d3.time.format("%d d"),
                fmon = d3.time.format("%b")
                ;


        function dsPieChart() {

            var dataset = [
                {category: "Tom", measure: 0.30},
                {category: "John", measure: 0.30},
                {category: "Martin", measure: 0.30},
                {category: "Sam", measure: 0.30},
                {category: "Peter", measure: 0.25},
                {category: "Johannes", measure: 0.15},
                {category: "Rick", measure: 0.05},
                {category: "Lenny", measure: 0.18},
                {category: "Paul", measure: 0.04},
                {category: "Steve", measure: 0.03}
            ]
                    ;

            var width = 400,
                    height = 400,
                    outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
                    innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,
                    // for animation
                    innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
                    innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius * .45,
                    color = d3.scale.category20()    //builtin range of colors
                    ;

            var vis = d3.select("#pieChart")
                    .append("svg:svg")              
                    .data([dataset])                  
                    .attr("width", width)          
                    .attr("height", height)
                    .append("svg:g")                
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")   
                    ;

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()             
                    .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);

            // for animation
            var arcFinal = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
            var arcFinal3 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()           
                    .value(function (d) {
                        return d.measure;
                    });   

            var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")     
                    .data(pie)                          
                    .enter()                            
                    .append("svg:g")                
                    .attr("class", "slice")    
                    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
                    .on("mouseout", mouseout)
                    .on("click", up)
                    ;

            arcs.append("svg:path")
                    .attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                        return color(i);
                    }) 
                    .attr("d", arc)     
                    .append("svg:title") 
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.data.category + ": " + formatAsPercentage(d.data.measure);
                    });

            d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
                    .duration(750)
                    .delay(10)
                    .attr("d", arcFinal)
                    ;

            arcs.filter(function (d) {
                return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2;
            })
                    .append("svg:text")
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")";
                    })

                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.data.category;
                    })
                    ;

            function angle(d) {
                var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
                return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
            }


            // Pie chart title          
            vis.append("svg:text")
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("Revenue Share 2012")
                    .attr("class", "title")
                    ;


            function mouseover() {
                d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                        .duration(750)
                        //.attr("stroke","red")
                        //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                        .attr("d", arcFinal3)
                        ;
            }

            function mouseout() {
                d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                        .duration(750)
                        //.attr("stroke","blue")
                        //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                        .attr("d", arcFinal)
                        ;
            }

            function up(d, i) {

                updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));
                updateLineChart(d.data.category, color(i));

            }
        }

        dsPieChart();


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: see this post it may help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939977/d3-js-spreading-labels-for-pie-charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of your code determines which slices get label text appended to them:

```
arcs.filter(function (d) {
    return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2;
})
.append("svg:text")...
```

So slices where the total arc angle is less than 0.2 radians will be filtered out, and label text will not be added.

You could just reduce the filter value, to display the labels on thinner slices (e.g. change `.2` in this example to `.05`) to get the effect you want:

[image: labels on smaller arcs]

Answer (score 0):

your very small data is not being displayed because it is being filtered out by this code. if you remove this piece of code, then those small data will also be displayed.

```
    arcs.filter(function (d) {
        return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2;
    })
```

However label will not be displayed clearly in small data. Displaying labels outside pie chart will display labels a bit clear.