# D3: pie labels with "horizontal ending"-lines without overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, lines

I really like David Buezas pie chart with lines, **especially those horizontal lines**, as they improve readability: http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799. But labels overlap there, lines potentially too.

Stumbled upon http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/11/solving-d3-label-placement-constraint-relaxing/ (contains a lot of fiddles, sorry, not enough reputation for posting link), which explains how to avoid overlapping. Tried to adapt this example to label lines with an "horizontal ending", basically by replacing `<line>` with `<polyline>`, but failed.

- It appears as `<line>` would have a different output than `<polyline>`, because I copied all the attributes, but it's drawn differently (pretty sure I didn't mess up)
- I obviously don't get how the lines are sliced to the text in Bueza's example. Thought I could just do a workaround by:

  - replacing `<line>` with `<polyline>`
  - copy attributes from `<line>` into `<polyine>`'s points attributes
  - add attribute that draws a straight, horizontal line to `<polyline>` by simply doing `last x-value + 30`
  - Then adapt text somehow with transform
  - Apart from the fact that this is a lot less elegant than Bueza's example, I also did not mind that one doesn't know if the horizontal line needs to go left or right (labels could be on both sides of the chart).

Can anyone please

- Tell me why `<line>`has a different output than `<polyline>`?
- Make that "Slice to text"-thing from Buezas example a little clearer to a newbie?

Here's my try: http://jsfiddle.net/HdwTH/40/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by "collapse"? Do you mean overlap?

Comment: Yes. That obviously was unclear, I changed it. Thank you Lars.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939977/d3-js-spreading-labels-for-pie-charts) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769872/d3-js-pie-chart-with-angled-horizontal-labels) do exactly the same thing you want to do if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939977/d3-js-spreading-labels-for-pie-charts) did the trick, especially the following lines (thanks a lot Lars for the hint).

```
/* check whether the default position 
       overlaps any other labels*/
    var conflicts = [];
    labelLayout.visit(function(node, x1, y1, x2, y2){
        //recurse down the tree, adding any overlapping labels
        //to the conflicts array

        //node is the node in the quadtree, 
        //node.point is the value that we added to the tree
        //x1,y1,x2,y2 are the bounds of the rectangle that
        //this node covers

        if (  (x1 > d.r + maxLabelWidth/2) 
                //left edge of node is to the right of right edge of label
            ||(x2 < d.l - maxLabelWidth/2) 
                //right edge of node is to the left of left edge of label
            ||(y1 > d.b + maxLabelHeight/2)
                //top (minY) edge of node is greater than the bottom of label
            ||(y2 < d.t - maxLabelHeight/2 ) )
                //bottom (maxY) edge of node is less than the top of label

              return true; //don't bother visiting children or checking this node

        var p = node.point;
        var v = false, h = false;
        if ( p ) { //p is defined, i.e., there is a value stored in this node
            h =  ( ((p.l > d.l) && (p.l <= d.r))
               || ((p.r > d.l) && (p.r <= d.r)) 
               || ((p.l < d.l)&&(p.r >=d.r) ) ); //horizontal conflict

            v =  ( ((p.t > d.t) && (p.t <= d.b))
               || ((p.b > d.t) && (p.b <= d.b))  
               || ((p.t < d.t)&&(p.b >=d.b) ) ); //vertical conflict

            if (h&&v)
                conflicts.push(p); //add to conflict list
        }

    });

    if (conflicts.length) {
        console.log(d, " conflicts with ", conflicts);  
        var rightEdge = d3.max(conflicts, function(d2) {
            return d2.r;
        });

        d.l = rightEdge;
        d.x = d.l + bbox.width / 2 + 5;
        d.r = d.l + bbox.width + 10;
    }
    else console.log("no conflicts for ", d);

    /* add this label to the quadtree, so it will show up as a conflict
       for future labels.  */
    labelLayout.add( d );
    var maxLabelWidth = Math.max(maxLabelWidth, bbox.width+10);
    var maxLabelHeight = Math.max(maxLabelHeight, bbox.height+10);
```

Here's the fiddle with the working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/1249/