# D3 does not maintain object constancy even when there is a key function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to write a reusable graph component using d3 (a pie chart in this particular scenario). I am new to d3 and also relatively inexperienced in writing highly reusable components. Here is what I have so far, I have displayed a pie chart using similar code by passing a key function to `data` but the object constancy somehow fails (the slices are out of order) when I am trying to make the same for reusable component.

I know there are a lot more concerns in this code regarding a lot more options that can be provided for the user and more cleaner code.

```
 function pieChart(){
        var _pie ={};
        var _width = 960,
                _height = 600,
                _margins = {top:30,left:30,right:30,bottom:30},
                _x,_y,_data = [],
                _color = d3.scale.category10(),
                _svg,
                _innerRadius=0,
                _radius = Math.min(_width,_height)/2 - (_margins.top/2 + _margins.bottom/2),  
                _layout = d3.layout.pie(),
                _key = function(d) { return d.data.key;},
                _value= function(d) { return d.data.val;},
                _bodyG,
                _arc;

        _pie.color = function(c){
            if(!arguments.legnth) return _color;
            _color = c;
            return  _pie;
        }

        _pie.value = function(v){
            if(!arguments.legnth) return _value;
            _value = v;
            return  _pie;
        }
        _pie.key = function(k){
            if(!arguments.legnth) return _key;
            _key= k;
            return  _pie;
        }
        _pie.width = function(w){
            if(!arguments.length) return _width;
            _width = w;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.height= function(h){
            if(!arguments.length) return _height;
            _height= h;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.margins = function(m){
            if(!arguments.length) return _margins;
            _margins = m;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.color= function(c){
            if(!arguments.length) return _color;
            _color = c;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.innerRadius= function(i){
            if(!arguments.length) return _innerRadius;
            _innerRadius = i;
            return _pie;
        }

        _pie.outerRadius= function(i,recalculate){
            recalculate = typeof recalculate !== 'undefined'? recalculate: false;
            if(!arguments.length){
                if(recalculate || !_radius)
                    _radius = Math.min(_width,_height)/2 - (_margins.top + _margins.bottom)/2;
                return _radius;
            }
            _radius= i;
            return _pie;
        }

        _pie.render= function(options){
            if(!_svg){
                _svg = d3.select("#pie-chart").append("svg")
                    .attr("height",_height)
                    .attr("width",_width)
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("transform","translate("+_width/2 + "," + _height/2 + ")");
            }
            if(options && options.layout) _layout= options.layout;

            if(options && options.sort) _layout.sort(options.sort);

            if(options && options.value) _layout.value(options.value);
            else _layout.value(function(d){return d.val});

            renderPie(_svg);
            renderLines(_svg);
            renderLabels(_svg);
        }

        _pie.layout = function(l){
            if(!arguments.length) return _layout;
            _layout = l;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.data=function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _data;
            _data = d;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.arc = function(a){
            if(!arguments.length){
                if(!_arc)
                _arc= d3.svg.arc()
                    .outerRadius(_radius)
                    .innerRadius(_innerRadius);
                return _arc;
            }
            _arc = a;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.key = function(k){
            if(!arguments.length || typeof k != 'function') return _key;
            _key = k;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.value= function(v){
            if(!arguments.length || typeof v != 'function') return _value;
            _value = v;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie._textPos= function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            var effectiveX = xc>0 ? _radius+50 : -_radius-50;
            var effectiveY = yc>0 ? (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)+50 : (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)-20;
            return "translate(" + effectiveX+ ","+effectiveY+")";
        }

        _pie.textPos = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _textPos;
            _textPos = d;
            return _pie;
        }

        _pie._arcIdentifier = function(d){
            return "each-arc-"+_key(d).toString().replace(/ /g,"_");
        }

        _pie._line1x1 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            return (r*xc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc);
        }
        _pie._line1x2 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            var xret= (r*xc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc);
            return xc>0 ? xret+50: xret-50;
        }
        _pie._line2x1 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            var xret= (r*xc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc);
            return xc>0 ? xret+50: xret-50;
        }
        _pie._line2x2 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            return xc>0 ? _radius+40: -_radius-40;
        }
        _pie._line1y1 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            return (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc);
        }

        _pie._line1y2 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            return yc>0 ? (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)+50 : (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)-20;
        }
        _pie._line2y1 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            return yc>0 ? (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)+50 : (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)-20;
        }
        _pie._line2y2 = function(d){
            var xc = _arc.centroid(d)[0];
            var yc = _arc.centroid(d)[1];
            var r = _radius -10;
            return yc>0 ? (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)+50 : (r*yc)/Math.sqrt(xc*xc + yc*yc)-20;
        }

        _pie.line1x1 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line1x1;
            _line1x1 = d;
            return _pie;
        }

        _pie.line1x2 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line1x2;
            _line1x2 = d;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.line1y1 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line1y1;
            _line1x1 = d;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.line1y2 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line1y2;
            _line1y2 = d;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.line2x1 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line2x1;
            _line2x1 = d;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.line2x2 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line2x2;
            _line2x2 = d;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.line2y1 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line2y1;
            _line2y1 = d;
            return _pie;
        }
        _pie.line2y2 = function(d){
            if(!arguments.length) return _line2y2;
            _line2y2 = d;
            return _pie;
        }



        function renderLabels(svg){
            _bodyG.append("text")
                .attr("transform",function(d){return _pie._textPos(d)})
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", function(d){return _pie.arc().centroid(d)[0]>0? "start":"end";})
                .text(_pie.key());
        }


        function renderPie(svg){
            _pie.arc();
            _bodyG = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                .data(_pie.layout()(_pie.data()),_pie.key()) //Worked perfectly before but now fails
                .enter().append("g")
                .order()
                .attr("class","arc");
            _bodyG.append("path")
                .attr("d",_arc)
                .attr("class",_pie._arcIdentifier)
                .style("fill",function(d){return _pie.color()(_pie.value()(d));})
        }
        function renderLines(svg){
            _bodyG.append("line")
                .attr("stroke","black")
                .attr("x1",_pie._line1x1)
                .attr("x2",_pie._line1x2)
                .attr("y1",_pie._line1y1)
                .attr("y2",_pie._line1y2);
            _bodyG.append("line")
                .attr("stroke","black")
                .attr("x1",_pie._line2x1)
                .attr("x2",_pie._line2x2)
                .attr("y1",_pie._line2y1)
                .attr("y2",_pie._line2y2);
        }
        return _pie;
    }
```

I am looking for an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769872/d3-js-pie-chart-with-angled-horizontal-labels)?

Comment: I am able to get the pie chart as I want it, what I am struggling with is the object constancy as the title indicates.

Comment: Your question doesn't say anything about what the problem is there.

Comment: I have made my problem description bold, please check it.

Comment: You say that "the object constancy somehow fails" -- what do you mean? Do you get any error messages? Do slices move around, are missing, do additional slices appear? The code you've provided isn't self-contained, so we can't actually run it.

Comment: oh, now I see where I was not clear, edited the question. The slices are out of order, that is my precise problem.

Comment: Did you verify that you key function returns what you expect it to return?

Comment: Yes, it returns unique string for each slice.

Comment: It looks like you're handling only the enter selection, so existing slices wouldn't be updated at all?

Comment: There is no update of the data, all the data is initially available. And I am trying to display it and it doesn't preserve the input order.

Comment: Well you're not handling the update selection at all. It looks like your key function isn't working and when you update, all slices are added again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69809/discussion-between-sasidhar-and-lars-kotthoff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clarification in chat: The problem isn't with object constancy, but with the slices of the pie being drawn in a different order than they are in the data.]

The problem is that you're asking the pie layout to sort the data:

```
_layout.sort(options.sort)
```

This rearranges the data and therefore the slices appear in a different order. To fix, you can either turn off sorting or give a key in the data that you can sort by to get the order you want.