# How to avoid overlap of text in D3 Simple Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

If I set very low values in my pie, I get overlap:

[image: d3 pie chart]

What options do I have to prevent overlapping?

Original example: http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2295263

My Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fekula/n908rqpx/

```
var dataSet = [
{"legendLabel":"One", "magnitude":1}, 
{"legendLabel":"Two", "magnitude":1}, 
{"legendLabel":"Three", "magnitude":1}, 
{"legendLabel":"Four", "magnitude":1}, 
{"legendLabel":"Five", "magnitude":1}, 
{"legendLabel":"Six", "magnitude":5}, 
{"legendLabel":"Seven", "magnitude":90}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use [angled labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769872/d3-js-pie-chart-with-angled-horizontal-labels) or the relaxation in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/thudfactor/HdwTH/).